# gfortran - Variable format expressions workaround

Tags: fortran

Trying to adapt an existing code to gfortran i came across variable format expressions, which are not supported by gfortran:

```
3022 format (a<ii>, ";", a<j>, ";", a10, ";", a10, ";", a10, ";", a10)
```

This expression is used in a write statement:

```
write(Resunit,3022)'author','EqType','pExp', 'prExp', 'pc', 'ec'
```

ii, and j are integers, describing variable string lengtghs.
I found a workaround [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Variable-FORMAT-expressions.html) but can't get it working for my case. Can anybody give me a hint how to get my expression compatible to gfortran?

greetings
bastian

Comment: What is the output you expect?  A complete self-contained minimum code would go a long way to explaining what you want.

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran].

Comment: If you cannot get the rewrite working then please ask about that attempt. Share your code and the errors and results you get. See [mcve]. Only then we can get you further hints.